# apache zeppelin fails on reading csv using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, spark-csv

I'm using `Zeppelin-Sandbox 0.5.6` with `Spark 1.6.1` on `Amazon EMR`.
I am reading `csv` file located on `s3`.
The problem is that *sometimes* I'm getting error reading the file. I need to restart the interpreter several times until it works. nothing in my code changes. I can't restore it, and can't tell when it's happening.

My code goes as following:

defining dependencies:

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0")
```

using `spark-csv`:

```
%pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df = sqlc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("s3://some_location/some_csv.csv")
```

error msg:

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o61.load. :
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
 Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-172-22-2-187.ec2.internal):
 java.io.InvalidClassException: com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation;
 local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
 2004612352657595167, local class serialVersionUID =
 6879416841002809418

 ...

 Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException:
 com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation; local class incompatible
```

Once I'm reading the `csv` into the `dataframe`, the rest of the code works fine.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute spark adding the spark-csv package to it like this

```
$ pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0
```

Now the spark-csv will be in your classpath